# Avahi commands not working in CentOS

Tags: centos, dns, avahi

I want to use Avahi tools for mDNS service discovery in CentOS 6.6. I have installed the following packages: avahi, avahi-tools, nss-mdns. I checked the Avahi daemon and it is running:

```
$ service avahi-daemon status
avahi-daemon (pid  1365) is running...
```

But when I tried running the following avahi-browse command, it halted there and returned nothing:

```
$ avahi-browse --all
```

When I tried to launch the Avahi GUI window like the following:

```
$ avahi-discover
bash: avahi-discover: command not found
```

Then I searched what Avahi-related packages are on my system:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep avahi
avahi-autoipd-0.6.25-15.el6.x86_64
avahi-tools-0.6.25-15.el6.x86_64
avahi-glib-0.6.25-15.el6.x86_64
avahi-0.6.25-15.el6.x86_64
avahi-libs-0.6.25-15.el6.x86_64
avahi-ui-0.6.25-15.el6.x86_64
```

I tried on another computer which runs on Ubuntu Linux and both avahi-browse and avahi-discover work fine. So why don't `avahi-browse` and `avahi-discover` work on my CentOS 6.6?

Answer (score 5):

avahi-browse, avahi-discover is part of avahi-tools rpm in centos 6.x

```
sudo yum install avahi-tools avahi-ui-tools
```

to find out:

```
sudo yum provides avahi-browser
```

Comment: The original question said "I have installed the following packages: avahi, avahi-tools ..." and you can see it in their output from `rpm -qa | grep avahi`.

Comment: Actually this post contains *the* correct answer to the `avahi-discover` problem (one of two separate problems in the question). It is a part of `avahi-ui-tools` which was not listed by OP. Suggested "how to find out"-way is correct, only the provided example is misleading.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure not just avahi-daemon works and is installed, but also avahi-utils. That was my problem.

On debian its

```
sudo apt-get install avahi-utils
```

I've never used CentOS, so I don't know how the package manager works, but it should be something similar.